# Database structure, how to think

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im making a football system were I put in all the games a team has played with results, participants for each game and if you have scored, you get an score + 1 in your profile for example.

The structure looking like this right now:

```
users:
ID - Name - Games - Wins - Losses - Goals - Assist - 2min

event:
ID - opponents - Results - UserID

Participants 
ID - UserID - EventID
```

And I wondering if this really is the best way, problem that I have found with this is that you can't see who has scored in which game for example since Im only updating the users table with + 1 in Goals. So now Im thinking off something like this:

```
users:
ID - Name

event:
ID - opponents - Results - UserID

Participants 
ID - UserID - EventID - Games - Wins - Losses - Goals - Assist - 2min
```

The good think here is that I can see which player has scored in which game, thats really nice to see! But in the userprofile, I have to count all goals from from participants table with the UserID on current user we are viewing, so the questions is, if I have shit loads of posts in participants will it take such a long time to run that query?

Thanks for input.

Update:

Lets say Im using the second option and want to count them.

```
$query = "SELECT count(assist) as aassist FROM `participants` WHERE `mid`='$q'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['aassist'];
```

I get a totally wrong number here if count them manually via PHPadmin.

Comment: You could always add a field to users table: total goals.. And update that accordingly to goals in an event.. than you just need 1 query to get data later, just a little more coding when adding scores..

Comment: I have been thinking of that as well. And Im thinking of going with that, will be easier in the long run I think. Thanks.

Comment: This is *often* a symptom of pre-optimisation.  If you start from a point of `store every individual item of known data separately` then you can always work out goals per player, per match, season, etc, etc.  The original `goals` field simply caches the result to avoid repeated processing, but locks down potential development scope in the future.  Start with the granular data that gives you maximum flexibility and only seek to cache / pre-calculate results as and when you actually identify them as real bottle necks rather than potential / theoretical bottle necks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have thousands of billions of records, there shouldn't be any performance issue with just SUM'ing it up from the Participants table, so I would go with the second approach.